# Double-slit experiment, coloured slits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Say, we can give colour while electron passing through slit. How would be the result, how would colours be distrubeted? Or, is it impossible to colour, somehow?

Comment: Electrons don't have colors; you could alter the spin. In this case the interference would vanish. Try reading the Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol III. This is an introduction to quantum physics.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Yes, altering spin does not work. But if we could label the slits such that when the electron passed through, slit leave a mark on it, without effecting the interference. Is it possible? I mean, the only way can't be to alter spin, right?

Comment: I've ask a somehow similar question about [Relation between the material properties of the obstacle and the fringes behind](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114384/relationship-between-the-material-properties-of-an-edge-and-the-fringes-behind-t).

Comment: @Behzat: after you have read Feynman's lectures you will understand the answer; or the Bohr-Einstein correspondence on variations of the same question: the answer is no.

Comment: @PeterDiehr thank you. then you should make that comment answer, i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrons don't have colors; however, you could alter the spin. In this case the interference would vanish.

For an interesting presentation by an expert, read the Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol III. This provides an excellent introduction to quantum physics:
http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

Another resource is the Einstein-Bohr correspondence, which investigates wonderful thought experiments constructed by Einstein in order to avoid the consequences of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. See this article, and references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Einstein_debates