# How Does the Electron Detector Detect Electrons? Dbl Slit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

The double slit experiment is famous for the electron acting like a particle rather than a wave when observed. Is it the case that the nature of the detection apparatus rather than passively taking readings actively interfered with the behavior of the electron in order to report, thus changing the electron's behavior?  In a previous post on this topic I saw references to entangling the electron with photons as the measurement tool. If so, surely this demystifies the entire result.

Comment: If you want to read a bit more about slit experiments see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363547/

Comment: Electrons never act like either particles or waves. They act like quanta of energy. Dirac has pointed out the futility of the wave-particle duality mental model in the early 1930s, so it's not a particularly new insight. It's just one that is generally being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In the publication [Demonstration of single‐electron buildup of an interference pattern](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.16104), which is not free access, one finds  the first experiment showing interference build up by single electrons. Record photographs have been provided by one of the authors in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) article  showing the interference pattern being built up.

[image]

See also the [video provided](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LVkQfCptEs) by one of the researchers, also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqS8Jjkk1HI).

The peer review of the experiment accepted the calculations and results and published it.

> Is it the case that the nature of the detection apparatus rather than passively taking readings actively interfered with the behavior of the electron in order to report, thus changing the electron's behavior

The experiment consists of scattering single electrons through an apparatus, so of course there is interference with the single electron behavior. It is the experiment “electron + specific double slits scattering” and the accumulating results give the probability distribution for this scatter. The single points are the footprints of the electron and the accumulation shows the interference pattern of a wave.

The detection measures the passing of an electron in the $(x,y)$ plane.

> The team created a double slit in a gold-coated silicon membrane, in which each slit is 62 nm wide and 4 μm long with a slit separation of 272 nm. To block one slit at a time, a tiny mask controlled by a piezoelectric actuator was slide back and forth across the double slits.
>
> The electrons were created at a tungsten filament and accelerated across 600 V and collimated into a beam. After passing through the double slit, they were detected using a [multichannel plate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchannel_plate_detector)

.....

> Batelaan told physicsworld.com that the experiment is particularly important from an outreach perspective because unlike the biprism experiments of the past, it actually uses a physical double slit and is therefore more accessible to the public.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeL, I gather that you're not referring to the detection screen where the patterns of inference take shape. To pinpoint the electron's path through the slits, an electron detector is typically positioned somewhere between the electron source and the detection screen, ideally in proximity to one of the slits. Electrons are detected or observed by illuminating them with photons, and your second statement is indeed accurate. The interaction between photons and electrons alters the trajectory of the electrons, leading to what is commonly known as the "Measurement Problem."