# Can the double slit experiment be answered with Einstein's gravitational lensing effect?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, gravitational-lensing

Since the original double slit experiment was done over 100 years ago, it probably wasn't done in a vacuum. I've noticed that the Einstein's lensing effect (or something similar) happens by looking past my finger and it can magnify objects about 12" away.  Could this be applied to the medium in which the photons are traveling through to get to the photon detector?  Assuming the medium is air and not vacuum, can we derive that the bands generated are in fact created by the photon being refocused by the edges of the oxygen atoms?

Comment: This is a heretic question. And a good one because you are thinking which is the second step after learning. If you don’t mind see my question about [Relationship between the material properties of an edge and the fringes behind this edge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114384/relationship-between-the-material-properties-of-an-edge-and-the-fringes-behind-t)

Comment: *"I've noticed that the Einstein's lensing effect (or something similar) happens by looking past my finger and it can magnify objects about 12" away."* It's not gravitational lensing. Do you have one or both eyes open? Can you photograph it?

Comment: Regarding the magnification effect, I wake up in the morning on the west side of the house and look out the window at the end of my bed.  There is a screen in the window I'm looking through.  With one eye closed and my finger about 12-13" from the window, the screen squares are visibly 2x-3x larger at the edge of my finger.  Note west side, not the side of sunrise in the morning.