# Diffraction of electron from single slit using time dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, diffraction, perturbation-theory

While reading about time dependent perturbation theory, I began wondering if it was possible to obtain the diffraction pattern by treating the walls as an infinite potential barrier and the slit as a no potential gap. Is this possible? If so, how would one go about it? If not, why?

Comment: [Can the intensity distribution behind edges and slits be explaint by the interaction with the surface electrons of the edges?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158105/)

Comment: [Deflection of electron beam on edges](https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges): The relation to your question se the last paragraph.

Comment: [Relationship between the material properties of an edge and the fringes behind this edge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114384/)